# Async/await with .map

Tags: javascript

I have an array called "clickables" that I want to map over and do something with each element. However, I want to map over it in order, and asynchronously wait. That means for this code:

```
 clickables = ['ele1', 'ele2', 'ele3']
 clickables.map(async ele => {
    await // action1
    await // action2
  });
```

I want ele1 to perform action 1 and then action 2.
Ele2 will wait for ele1 to finish, and then perform action 1 and then action 2.
Ele3 will wait for ele2 to finish, and so on.

Async await within the map obviously makes sure action 1 is performed before action 2 for each individual element, but it does not ensure that we wait for ele1 to finish before ele2 executes.

How can I do this?

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the return value of `map` so you shouldn't be using `map` in the first place. `forEach` would make more sense, but it won't work with `async` functions in the way that you want (and nor will `map`).

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vq6jcy

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd probably be better off using a loop instead of `map`. You could do it pretty easily like this:

```js
clickables = ['ele1', 'ele2', 'ele3'];
(async () => {
  for (const e of clickables) {
    await console.log(`${e}-1`);
    await console.log(`${e}-2`);
  }
})();
```

You can supposedly use `reduce` for functionality like this, but it is much more complicated syntactically, and I would argue that this is much easier to follow and readable. See this [CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/why-using-reduce-to-sequentially-resolve-promises-works/) about it.

Comment: ``clickables.reduce((p, e) => p.then(async () => {
  await console.log(`${e}-1`); await console.log(`${e}-2`);
}), Promise.resolve())`` doesn't seem that much more complicated.